# The client is using an unsupported version of the Socket.IO or Engine.IO protocols (further occurrences of this error will be logged with level INFO)

Tags: websocket, socket.io, flask-socketio, python-sockets, flask-sockets

I am using Flask and SocketIO.
I am getting
`The client is using an unsupported version of the Socket.IO or Engine.IO protocols (further occurrences of this error will be logged with level INFO)` on my Flask console.

Here are my versions:

```
bidict==0.22.1
click==8.1.3
colorama==0.4.6
Flask==2.2.2
Flask-SocketIO==5.3.6
h11==0.14.0
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.2
MarkupSafe==2.1.1
numpy==1.25.1
opencv-python==4.8.0.74
python-engineio==4.8.0
python-socketio==5.10.0
simple-websocket==1.0.0
six==1.16.0
Werkzeug==2.2.2
wsproto==1.2.0
```

At the end of my body in HTML, I have these lines:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="{{url_for('static', filename='js/video.js')}}"></script>
```

At the top of my video.js file, I have this line:

```
import io from '/socket.io/socket.io.js';
var socket = io();
```

In my Flask project, which I have organized as a package, I have these lines in **init**.py:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
socketio = SocketIO(app)
```

Additionally, I have a file called run.py, which contains the following:

```
from mypackage import app, socketio

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

I have tried downgrading to socketio version 4.3.2 which simply causes a Werkzeug error compatibility issue for some odd reason.

I have looked online for a lot of solutions that have not helped.

It is my understanding that the socket.io.js file is being generated by the Flask socketio so it should be automatically compatible?

I tried looking into the Javascript file in developer tools. When accessing the link in by copying the url http://127.0.0.1:5000/socket.io/socket.io.js, I merely get a text body of "The client is using an unsupported version of the Socket.IO or Engine.IO protocols".

I have spent close to 3 hours on this issue already. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty clear: "The **client** is using an unsupported version of ...". The problem is that the version of your client here:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

is incompatible with the version of the server here:

```
python-engineio==4.8.0
python-socketio==5.10.0
```

So first determine what version of the client you have, then look at the version compatibility table in [the documentation](https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html#version-compatibility) to make sure you are using a set of compatible versions across client and server.